# How to set a default photo in cardview using recylerview in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I have a cardview using recyclerview list in which data of user is showing. Data coming from server.. but i want to set a default user photo if user doesn't upload his own photo then dummy photo should be shown in imageview.. please guide me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a ImageView-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_user_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/default_photo" //your default photo
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whe you receive the server photo, just put them in `image_view_user_photo`, case the user haven't photo the default photo will not changed